# Is there an alternative/customizer app for Cmd+Tab that does not show minimized/hidden windows and apps?

Tags: window-manager

Is there an alternative/customizer app for <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> that does not show minimized/hidden windows and apps?

Sometimes I have many apps running (Calendar, Mail, Twitter, etc.), but all of them are minimized and my focus is on, say, two apps: my IDE and the browser.

So I want <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to only show my browser and IDE.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hold command and quickly tap tab you will cycle between your two most recently used applications without bringing up the heads up display.

If you want to use a third party app [Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/) has options to ignore minimized windows.

Comment: quick tab tapping won't work for cycling between more than 2 apps. Witch looks good, and can ignore minimized windows, but can't ignore hidden ones.

Comment: You could also permanently remove applications from view of Command Tab with http://foggynoggin.com/dockdodger They could be in the dock but wouldn't have an indicator light.